# How to replace text of element after AJAX request using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using Jquery V1.11.1 and I want to replace a cell in a HTML table after a Jquery AJAX request. I want the result in the cell.

```
    $(".permission").click(function(e) {
    var acoPath = $(this).siblings('th').text();
    var rowsLeft = $(this).prevUntil("th").length;
    var aroGroup = $('.aro').eq(rowsLeft).text();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/permissions/update",
        type: "POST",
        data: { aco : acoPath, aro : aroGroup },
        cache: false,
        dataType: "HTML",
        success: function (html) {
            $(this).html(html);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

When I click on the text in the desired cell, nothing is replaced. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the context in ajax call to current object. You can use context option from ajax to do that:

```
context: this,
```

Modified ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/permissions/update",
    type: "POST",
    context: this,
    data: { aco : acoPath, aro : aroGroup },
    cache: false,
    dataType: "HTML",
    success: function (html) {
        $(this).html(html);
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your context has changed. in the '`click`' function `this` referce to the button. But in the callback function the context has changed. You should save the context to a variable first (`var self`).

```
$(".permission").click(function(e) {
var acoPath = $(this).siblings('th').text();
var rowsLeft = $(this).prevUntil("th").length;
var aroGroup = $('.aro').eq(rowsLeft).text();
var self = this;

$.ajax({
    url: "/permissions/update",
    type: "POST",
    data: { aco : acoPath, aro : aroGroup },
    cache: false,
    dataType: "HTML",
    success: function (html) {
        self.html(html);
    }
    });
});
```

});